# Adding a string inside a node of an XML object using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

This is my first time doing anything with XML. I'm working with a script (I'm not the original author) that outputs an XML object like so:

```
var myUrl = <ajaxXmlObject><textarea>"http://examplewebsite.com/?page=home&parameterA=x&parameterB=y"</textarea></ajaxXmlObject>
```

Is there any way, using jQuery or JavaScript, of accessing the `<textarea>` node and concatenating a string to the URL?  So far my research has come up short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `getElementsByTagName` in combination with an `innerHTML` method worked for me. You also need to make sure the new string is formatted properly for XML.

```
var myUrl = <ajaxXmlObject><textarea>"http://examplewebsite.com/?page=home&parameterA=x&parameterB=y"</textarea></ajaxXmlObject>;

var stringOfNewContent = "&amp;more-stuff&amp;even-more-stuff";

responseUrl.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML += stringOfNewContent;
```

This now returns:

```
responseUrl = <ajaxXmlObject><textarea>"http://examplewebsite.com/?page=home&parameterA=x&parameterB=y&more-stuff&even-more-stuff"</textarea></ajaxXmlObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your xml in a jquery object then reference/update the node text.

```js
var myObj = $('<ajaxXmlObject><textarea>"http://examplewebsite.com/?page=home&parameterA=x&parameterB=y"</textarea></ajaxXmlObject>');

var url = myObj.find('textarea').text().replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
url += "&some=stuff";
myObj.find('textarea').text('"' + url + '"')

alert(myObj.find('textarea').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I added some handling to maintain the double quotes. I am not sure if you need that or not.

Comment: Thanks. This got me partially there, but I was actually hoping to keep the original structure of the tags in tact.  I'm posting my solution below.

Comment: Cool, curious what you came up with.